# Is it possible to create "templates" for subpages?

Tags: javascript, php, html, templates

I am new to programming.
My question is the following:

Is there some kind of template for subpages, for example on the homepage of the website.

I would like to create a few sub-pages that have the same structure, but deal with a different topic.

Is there something I can read into or something I can find out about?

Comment: You can create it with simple php ,  html  and web components ( inbuilt in js ) or use react ( or vue ) for certain components to update

Comment: You've tagged this with PHP so [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) is basically what you're looking for. The basic idea is that you have a `index.php` file containing the main HTML head and layout, then insert another .php file in the main content area. Note that PHP was initially created to do exactly what you're looking: avoid all the duplicate HTML that comes with static pages.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a programming language and it is also a template engine. There are several ways to tackle the problem you have outlined.

Index.php would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div><a href="topic.php?a=lions">Lions</a></div>
    <div><a href="topic.php?a=narwhals">Narwhals</a></div>
    <div><a href="topic.php?a=chimps">Chimps</a></div>
    <div><a href="topic.php?a=hawk">Hawk</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

topic.php

```
<?php

class TopicData
{
    // Use a static function to get the data for a keyword
    public static function text($keyword){
        $file = "topics.json";
        // If the file doesn't exist, just say there is no data
        if ( ! file_exists($file) ) {
            return "No information on topic";
        }
        $topics = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
        $text = $topics->{$keyword} ?? "No information on topic";
        return $text;
    }
}
$text = TopicData::text($_GET['a']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="">
        <?= $text ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

topic.json

I use a json file to store some test data.

```
{
    "lions": "Lions go here",
    "narwhals": "Narwhals have tusks",
    "chimps": "Chimps can't read",
    "hawk": "Hawks fly iini the day time"
}
```